# how to overwrite the success function via JQuery ajaxSend event

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to overwrite the success function upon ajaxsend event but it doesnt work
here is the code:

```
    $(document).ajaxSend(function(event,xhr,options){
        console.log('ajaxSend');
        var tempSuccess = options.success;
        options.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log('start');
            tempSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            console.log('end');
        }; xhr.success = options.success;});
```

upon AJAX I do see 'ajax' in the console, but upon success I can't see the start and the end debug msges..

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293668/jquery-ajax-prevent-callback-from-running

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't answer my question, ajaxComplete fires after the browser gets the HTTP response, i am asking about ajaxSend which fires before the HTTP request

Comment: You're right. I was just pointing at the answer which says that callbacks are bound to be run and that you can't prevent that. Granted it's not exactly your question; I'm interested in a solution as well.

Comment: Other people and I need something that works without JQuery. We wish that other people will provide code that can do that without jQuery..I have upvoted your answer. thanks!

Comment: What I mean is that I don't mind that you are using jQuery to do what you do, but you can't assume that the developer is using jQuery in order to initiate AJAX calls

Comment: Why did you tag your question with "jQuery" then? oO My answer works perfectly for jQuery and also provides a basic solution for non-jQuery requests. Your question is completely misleading.

Answer (score 7):

What you're trying to accomplish can't be done with `ajaxSend`. The problem is that `ajaxSend` apparently works with a copy of the original `xhr` and `options` objects, so the modifications won't have any effect. You can easily test this with the following code:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, options){
    delete options.success;
    console.log(options.success);   // undefined
});
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function() { console.log("this will be printed nevertheless"); }
});
```

So you can't use `ajaxSend` to overwrite the success callbacks. Instead, you will have to "hack" jQuery's AJAX function:

```
// closure to prevent global access to this stuff
(function(){
    // creates a new callback function that also executes the original callback
    var SuccessCallback = function(origCallback){
        return function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("start");
            if (typeof origCallback === "function") {
                origCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
            console.log("end");
        };
    };

    // store the original AJAX function in a variable before overwriting it
    var jqAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(settings){
        // override the callback function, then execute the original AJAX function
        settings.success = new SuccessCallback(settings.success);
        jqAjax(settings);
    };
})();
```

Now you can simply use `$.ajax` as usual:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    success: function() {
        console.log("will be printed between 'start' and 'end'");
    }
});
```

As far as I know, any of jQuery's AJAX functions (such as `$.get()` or `.load()`) internally use `$.ajax`, so this should work with every AJAX request done via jQuery (I haven't tested this though...).

---

Something like that should also work with "pure" JavaScript by hacking the `XMLHttpRequest.prototype`. Note that the following won't work in IE, which uses `ActiveXObject` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
(function(){
    // overwrite the "send" method, but keep the original implementation in a variable
    var origSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(data){
        // check if onreadystatechange property is set (which is used for callbacks)
        if (typeof this.onreadystatechange === "function") {
            // overwrite callback function
            var origOnreadystatechange = this.onreadystatechange;
            this.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log("start");
                }
                origOnreadystatechange();
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log("end");
                }
            };
        }
        // execute the original "send" method
        origSend.call(this, data);
    };
})();
```

Usage (just like a usual XMLHttpRequest):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "test.html", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log("will be printed between 'start' and 'end'");
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: what would you do for non-jquery ajax requests?

Comment: See above, I've edited my answer... But I guess there's more to it, so perhaps you should open a separate question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Because the option.success is used before ajaxSend. When it was used,it was added to the Deferred Object.

After that,you change the option.success, nothing will happen.

So, you must change it before is was used. the process is:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter -- $.fn.ajaxStart(if needed) -- option.beforeSend -- 
USE option.success and option.error and option.complete -- 
$.ajaxTransport -- $.fn.ajaxSend -- send the actual request -- 
option.dataFilter --  fire the success/error callbacks -- 
$.fn.ajaxSuccess/$.fn.ajaxError -- fire the complete callbacks --  
$.fn.ajaxComplete -- $.fn.ajaxStop(if needed)
```

So, you can change the option.success in "$.ajaxPrefilter" or "option.beforeSend".

Answer (score -1):

You could use closures to accomplish what you need:

```
function closure(handler) {
    return function(ev, xhr, options) {
        console.log("start");
        handler(ev, xhr, options);
        console.log("stop");
    }
}

$(document).ajaxSend(closure(function(ev, xhr, options) {
    console.log("hello");
}));
```

Comment: This does not work as intended as it doesn't overwrite the success callback function! The "closure" function doesn't have any effect; `console.log('start/end')` could as well be moved into `ajaxSend` here. Basically your "solution" is just code obfuscation...

Comment: Clearly I misunderstood author intent, sorry for that.

As for $.get and $.load they do use $.ajax internally as can be seen here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js